# Pass JS foreach to JS post without form

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, post

`totalforms[i]` is reading all inputs from page (dynamically generated) (eg: `<input name="test" type="text">`)
I want to send all inputs (get from foreach in JS array) to `https://example.com/client_area?add_to_cart<?php echo $product_id; ?>`.

Function to post data (JS):

```
function post(path, params, method='post') {

              const form = document.createElement('form');
              form.method = method;
              form.action = path;

              for (const key in params) {
                if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                  const hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
                  hiddenField.type = 'hidden';
                  hiddenField.name = key;
                  hiddenField.value = params[key];

                  form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                }
              }

              document.body.appendChild(form);
              form.submit();
            }
```

Function to run getting of all inputs in page:

```
function runToCart() {
      var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      document.getElementById("addToCart").innerHTML = `Add To Cart   <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>`;
      var totalforms = new Array();
      var totalforms_values = new Array();
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        totalforms.push(forms[i].name);
        totalforms_values.push(forms[i].value);
      }
      post('/client_area?add_to_cart=<?php echo $product; ?>', {names: totalforms, values: totalforms_values});
    }
```

so?
I tried to search, but nothing like that specific found.

**P.S: i want to make an array for array like `totalforms[number_if_input_name]['value_of_name_of_input']`**

**SOLVED BY ADDING form= attribute in my inputs, no need js anymore here.**

Comment: This line should use form tag not input tag I think var forms = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

Comment: Edited runToCart, now (for example), totalforms_values[1] is totalforms[1], i sent post to page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill an object with data

```
let totalforms = {};
for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
  totalforms[i] = totalforms[i] || {};
  totalforms[i][forms[i].name] = forms[i].value;
}
```